# How to find and replace particular pattern in notepad++?

Tags: regex, expression, notepad++

The base file consist of multiple lines:

```
SA.PRC_UPD_ATTR (276135642, '90027876', 'NEXUS_A_M01817');
SA.PRC_UPD_ATTR (276135643, '90027876', 'ZEETA_A_010018V');
SA.PRC_UPD_ATTR (276135647, '90027876', 'PHOTON-JK_B_010S1817');
```

The expected output after replace should give

```
SA.PRC_UPD_ATTR (276135642, '90027876', 'A');
SA.PRC_UPD_ATTR (276135643, '90027876', 'A');
SA.PRC_UPD_ATTR (276135647, '90027876', 'B');
```

i.e. extract data between _ _ from last parameter.
Replacing , '.*?_ with ' doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'[^_']*_([^'_]+)_[^']+'(?=\s*\);)
```

Try this.Replace by `'$1'` or `'\1'`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/rA7aS3/7

Answer (score 0):

Replace this pattern:

```
(SA\.PRC_UPD_ATTR\s+\(\d+,\s*'\d+',\s*').*?_(.+?)_.*?('\s*\);)
```

With:

```
$1$2$3
```